# Find object in child class from parent class instance in django

Tags: django

Let's say I have a parent class (Products) and  child class related by OneToOneField. Now let's say I have a Products instance object. How will I be able to access all the fields of child ?

```
 class Products(models.Model):
           ......

  class Child1(models.Model):
          parent=models.OneToOneField(Products)
           ......

  class Child2(models.Model):
          parent=models.OneToOneField(Products)
           ......
```

Now let
        product_instance=Products.objects.get(id=id)

How can I access child fields without knowing the child class name?

Comment: All fields of _which_ child? There can be both a `Child1` and a `Child2` instance (and even more related objects that you may not know) related to the `product_instance`. You can't access the child (actually it's not a parent/child relation since it is one-to-one, but anyways) without knowing its name. It does not make sense either. If you can explain what you are trying to accomplish we might be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

There is package called DeepCollector using this you can get all related objects

```
from deep_collector.core import DeepCollector

collector = DeepCollector()
collector.collect(Products)
related_objects = collector.get_collected_objects()
```

try this...